# Finding the closest web-safe colour using .net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, colors, web-safe-colors

I would like an app that tells me the closest websafe colour to a given RGB or HEX value.

For example, given #FFFF01 or 255,255,1 I'd like to know the closest .net colour is `Color.Yellow` (255,255,0)

Does anyone know of a good app, or website that will achieve this?

I don't want to convert the colours, I know how to do that. In my code I would like to type `Color.Yellow` instead of `Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 1)`

Comment: doesn't sound hard to write, but human perception is a funny thing.

Comment: It sounds like plotting all the websafe colors in 3-space and then finding the one with the shortest distance to the input color would be easy. But I feel it would be wrong.

Comment: It isn't something I have time to spend on - looking around though it seems quite complex?

Comment: @Flame, apparently you should use HSL or HLV rather than RGB otherwise you end up with some greys being closer to green etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one looks more like it:

http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#FFFF01

You type in your HEX color code and it tells you the closest named color.

Here's another one that has source code too:

http://shallowsky.com/colormatch/index.php?hex=ffff01